# Navigating within chart area after a zoom-in

Tags: highcharts, zooming, drag, double-click

I have a very simple case of Highcharts scatter plot chart (with many points), box-zooming enabled.
What I'd need would be to drag-navigate across the chart area, just like on a google map for example.

Is there a way to zoom-in/out on left/right-double-click events (instead of boxing), then drag around as mouse button remains down?

Thank you.

Comment: So you would like to have kind of slider, which allows to zoom in/out ?

Comment: This would be very interesting for me also. Anyone has any solutions to this?